# How can I use color name or rgb code in cycler color

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am using cycler to automate profiles plot. Each color is repeated 12 times. Currently, I define the used color with letter but I would like to use color name or rgb code to get more options.

Currently I have:

```
colors = cycle('k'*12 + 'y'*12 + 'g'*12 + 'r'*12 + 'b'*12)
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
colors = cycle('gray1'*12 + 'gold4'*12 + 'forestgreen'*12 + 'firebrick'*12 + 'dodgerblue4'*12)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Could you make your code reproducible, especially by adding the exact imports used? You could try proving a list of colors instead of a string with single-letter colors, `cycler(color=['gray1']*12 + ['gold4']*12 + ['forestgreen']*12)`.  See https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html

Comment: [List of named colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import cycle, repeat, chain, starmap
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from cycler import cycle
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

colors_rgb = [(0, 0, 0), (142, 68, 173),(192, 57, 43),(241, 196, 15),(46, 204, 113),]
colors_norm = [(r / 255, g / 255, b / 255) for r, g, b in colors_rgb]
colors_rgb_repeated = [mcolors.rgb2hex(colors_norm) for colors_norm in colors_norm for _ in range(12)]
colors = cycle(colors_rgb_repeated)
```

Comment: Note that matplotlib interprets triples of 3 integers as rgb value in the range 0-255. The conversion to float values between 0 and 1 isn't necessary, nor is it necessary to convert the values to hex. You can also just use color names instead of rgb values.  Further, note that you imported `cycle` twice: `from itertools import cycle` and `from cycler import cycle`; it would be less confusing if you removed the first import.

Comment: Thanks! 

I try `colors_rgb_repeated = [mcolors.rgb2hex(colors_norm) for colors_norm in colors_norm for _ in range(12)]` but I obtain `ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range`

Comment: `rgb2hex` wants its rgb values normalized, but matplotlib itself directly accepts integer triples.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).